# How do I organize a "data grid"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am working on building a webpage like the picture below. I am trying to find the best way to organize the data the way I want. I am working with a grid view and is not doing what I want.

- How can I put the data together in the same column cell?
- Do I have to use something different like a Data List or similar?
- How do I put a button inside a Data Grid?

Sorry if the questions are misleading or dim-witted.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this problem would be better suited to using HTML within a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  All a Gridview will render is a HTML table which I don't believe is best for this problem.

A [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will also accept a datasource in the same way a gridview will, and you just bind the seperate elements within the markup.

So the code would look something like:

```
<asp:Repeater id=Repeater1 runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       //Put the HTML for one box here and bind data with:
       <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater
```

Answer (score 1):

Use repeaters. Repeaters will let you render your own html.